# How to make HTML validation work with onclick="form.submit()" instead of a type="submit" button/input

Tags: html, validation, constraint-validation-api

I have a form with the following code:

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="https://pilot.datatrans.biz/upp/jsp/getCcAliasFormMod.jsp" id="form_payment_cc" name="uppform">
    <label for"cvv">CVV</label><br />
    <input type="text" size="4" id="cvv" name="cvv" value="" required="required" />
    <p></p>
    <div class="order">
        <div></div> <div><a href="#" onclick="javascript:$( '#form_payment_cc' ).submit();"><img src="/images/pfeil_orange.png" style="margin-left: 30px;"><strong>Weiter</strong></a></div>
        </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="LaBK9OAZyhjENzWmCiCokS0kGXgFmbPNm7v1lo1LuRs" />
</form>
```

The form contains elements with the `required="required"` attribute. Unfortunately, for design reasons, I cannot use `<input type="submit" />` to submit a form. Instead, I use `<a onclick="form.submit()"></a>`. HTML validation does not work when I try to submit this way.

Any ideas as to why? Are there ways to trigger HTML validation without using a submit button (I know that everything works when I use a regular submit button)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<a onclick="if(form.checkValidity()) form.submit()"></a>`

Though it might be better to use CSS to apply your custom design and use native buttons.

**Update**:

It seems a regular button is required to trigger native validation. So a possible solution would be to use a hidden button and trigger a click using JS:

```
<form>
  <input name="email" type="email" title="Enter your email" required />
  <input id="sumbitBtn" type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px" /> 
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('sumbitBtn').click();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

For a CSS based solution (no JS required) using a regular button check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaZDn/213/)

Comment: Does checkValidity() trigger the native error messages?

Comment: No it is not. You need a regular button. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! In Firefox 28 on Ubuntu the native error messages are not shown. However, the form does not validate and the empty fields are surrounded by a red line.

Comment: Try the CSS based approach. And don`t forget to vote if an answer was helpful :)

Comment: Since a few browsers do not support native error messages, I came to the conclusion that it was best to use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ I still don't have enough rep points to vote for your answers - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the native error messages that some browsers have (such as Chrome), unfortunately the only way to do that is by submitting the form, like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <a href="#" id="mylink"> submit </a>
</form>
```

and then:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Like I said above, it works perfectly with a regular submit button. Also, what you suggested is basically the same as what I did anyway.

Comment: Can you maybe edit your post and add the whole code of the form and also the js you are using?